# Ajax content is being loaded regardless of if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a div being loaded with ajax but I wanted to add an if statement to only load the ajax if it is not already loaded. For some reason this isn't working on my [site](http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/homesite/)( Click on the left eye to see the error. ). Instead, the ajax content slides in and then the content is reloaded via ajax.

Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        function SlideOut(element) {
            var opened = $(".opened"),
                div = $("#" + element),
                content = $("#content");
            opened.removeClass("opened");
            div.addClass("opened");
            content.removeClass().addClass(element);
        }
        $("#content div").click(
            function () {
                var move = $(this).attr('data-move'),
                    id   = $(this).attr("id");
                if( id == 'forehead')
                {
                    $('#resume img').css('display', 'block');
                }

                else if(id =='left-eye23')
                {   
                    var  leftcontent;
                    leftcontent = $("#left-content");                       
                    content = leftcontent.attr('class');
                    if( !leftcontent.hasClass('photos'))
                    {       
                      SlideOut(move);
                        $("#left").bind("webkitTransitionEnd mozTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend", 
                        function(){ 
                            $.ajax({
                            url:'photos.php',
                            beforeSend: function(){
                                leftcontent.html('<img src="loading.gif" /> Now loding...');
                            },
                            }).done(function(data){
                                leftcontent.html(data);
                                leftcontent.addClass("photos");
                            }); 
                            });
                        }                       
                    else if (leftcontent.hasClass('photos'))
                    {
                      SlideOut(move); 
                    }

                }...
```

Comment: The link to the website seems incorrect. Could you rectify it.

Comment: @PranavKapoor wow yea thanks a lot, too many www's thanks again

Answer (score 1):

`if(leftcontent.length == 0)` should do the trick.

So it would look like:

```
var leftcontent = $("#left-content");                       
if(leftcontent.length == 0)
{
     //Do stuff
}
```

If you console.log an element it will return a length. If the object doesn't exist the length is 0.
This if will only run if there is no #left-content on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
leftcontent.html(data);
```

To:

```
$("#left-content").html(data)
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference? Is the DOM element with that ID changing after the variable is assigned?

Comment: i think it might be re-initializing the photos and so it looks like it is loading (i am also using [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/))